# How do I get the total number of blocks in a Blockly workspace

Tags: blockly

If I have a Blockly workspace, how can I get the total number of blocks that are being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`workspace.getAllBlocks(false).length`

Docs: https://developers.google.com/blockly/reference/js/Blockly.Workspace#getAllBlocks